# i am trying to implement a "upload image from device" in my mern stack app but its just not working

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, mongoose, mern

i am trying to implement a "upload image from device" in my mern stack app but its just not working i added everything that has to do with uploading a picture but working with backend is pretty new to me and i am not sure what i did wrong
it wont upload any images i keep getting this error Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'uploads/image1.png'
even tho i have the uploads folder and i also manually added the image1.png to it to try and retrieve it but its not working
this is what i get in insomnia
[insomnia error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmgUQ.png)

this is my index.js

```
import express from "express";
import cors from "cors";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import { userRouter}  from "./routes/user.js"
import { bookRouter}  from "./routes/book.js"

const app = express();

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());
app.use("/auth", userRouter);
app.use("/book", bookRouter);

mongoose.connect(
    "mongodb+srv://rawanarafat:password@books.8os64q7.mongodb.net/books?retryWrites=true&w=majority", //chnage this to your mongodb one for that specific app
    {
      useNewUrlParser: true,
      useUnifiedTopology: true,
    }
  );

app.listen(2001, () => console.log("Server started"));
```

this is home.js

```
import React from "react";
import {  useEffect } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useGetUserID } from "../hooks/getUserID";
import { useState } from "react";

export const Home = () => {
  const [books, setBooks] = useState([]);

  const userid = useGetUserID();

  const [image, setImage] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchBooks = async () => {
      try {
        const result = await axios.get(
          `http://localhost:2001/book/books/${userid}`
        );
        setBooks(result.data);
        console.log(result.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };

    
    fetchBooks();
    
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <h1>Book You Have Read</h1>
      <ul>
        {books.toReversed().map((book) => (
          <li key={book._id}>
            <div>
              {image ? (
                <img
                  src={`http://localhost:2001/uploads/${image.filename}`}
                  alt="Uploaded"
                />
              ) : (
                <p>No image available</p>
              )}
              <h2>{book.title}</h2>
            </div>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    </div>
  );
};
```

this is the book route

```
import express from "express";
import jwt from "jsonwebtoken";
import bcrypt from "bcrypt";
import mongoose from "mongoose";
import multer from "multer";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from "uuid";
import path from "path";


const router = express.Router();
import { UserModel } from "../models/Users.js";
import { BookModel } from "../models/Books.js";



const storage = multer.diskStorage({
  destination: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, 'server/src/uploads');
  },
  filename: function (req, file, cb) {
    cb(null, file.originalname);
  },
});

const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
  const allowedfileTypes = ["image/jpeg", "image/jpg", "image/png"];
  if (allowedfileTypes.includes(file.mimetype)) {
    cb(null, true);
  } else {
    cb(null, false);
  }
};
let upload = multer({ storage, fileFilter });

router.get("/", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const book = await BookModel.find({});
    res.status(200).json(book);
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

// Create a new book
router.post("/", upload.single('imageUrl'), async (req, res) => {
  
  console.log('Uploaded File:', req.file);
  let imageUrl = "";
    if (req.file) {
      imageUrl = req.file.filename;
    }
  const book = new BookModel({
    _id: new mongoose.Types.ObjectId(),
    title: req.body.title,
    author: req.body.author,
    pageCount: req.body.pageCount,
    genra: req.body.genra,
    datePublished: req.body.datePublished,
    format: req.body.format,
    startDate: req.body.startDate,
    endDate: req.body.endDate,
    stars: req.body.stars,
    bookFeel: req.body.bookFeel,
    summary: req.body.summary,
    review: req.body.review,
    notes: req.body.notes,
    imageUrl: imageUrl,
    userOwner: req.body.userOwner,
  });
  /*console.log(book);*/

  try {
    const result = await book.save();

    res.status(201).json({
      createdBook: {
        title: result.title,
        imageUrl: result.imageUrl,
        author: result.author,
        pageCount: result.pageCount,
        genra: result.genra,
        datePublished: result.datePublished,
        format: result.format,
        startDate: result.startDate,
        endDate: result.endDate,
        stars: result.stars,
        bookFeel: result.bookFeel,
        summary: result.summary,
        review: result.review,
        notes: result.notes,
        _id: result._id,
      },
    });
  } catch (err) {
    // console.log(err);
    res.status(500).json(err);
  }
});

router.get("/books/:userid", async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const user = await UserModel.findById(req.params.userid);
    const books = await BookModel.find({ userOwner: user._id });
    console.log(books);
    res.status(200).json(books);
  } catch (error) {
    res.json(error);
  }
});



// Route for handling image uploads
router.post("/upload", upload.single("imageUrl"), async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const file = req.file;
    if (!file) {
      res.status(400).json({ error: "No file uploaded" });
      return;
    }

    // Save the file information to the book document in MongoDB
    const bookId = req.body.bookId; // Assuming you have a bookId associated with the file upload
    try {
      const updatedBook = await Book.findByIdAndUpdate(
        bookId,
        { imageUrl: file.filename },
        { new: true }
      );
      // Handle the updated book
      res.status(200).json({ imageUrl: file.filename });
    } catch (error) {
      // Handle the error
      res.status(500).json({ error: "Failed to save file information" });
      return;
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
    res.status(500).json({ error: "Internal server error" });
  }
});

export { router as bookRouter };
```

this is books schema

```
import mongoose from "mongoose";

const BookSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  author: { type: String, required: false },
  pageCount: { type: Number, required: false },
  genra: { type: String, required: false },
  datePublished: { type: Date, required: false },
  format: { type: [String], required: false, enum: ['Book', 'E-book', 'AudioBook'] },
  startDate: { type: Date, required: false },
  endDate: { type: Date, required: false },
  stars: {type: Number, required: false, min: 0, max: 5},
  bookFeel: {type: Number, required: false, min: 0, max: 7},
  summary: { type: String, required: false},
  review: { type: String, required: false},
  notes: { type: String, required: false},
  imageUrl: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed, required: false },
  userOwner: {type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,ref: "User", required: true,
  },
});

export const BookModel = mongoose.model("books", BookSchema);
```

this is the create-book.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";
import { useGetUserID } from "../hooks/getUserID";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { useCookies } from "react-cookie";

export const CreateBook = () => {
  const userID = useGetUserID();
  const [cookies, _] = useCookies(["access_token"]);
  const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = useState(null);
  const [book, setBook] = useState({
    title: "",
    author: "",
    pageCount: "",
    genra: "",
    datePublished: "",
    format: "Book",
    startDate: "",
    endDate: "",
    stars: 5,
    bookFeel: 4,
    summary: "",
    review: "",
    notes: "",
    imageUrl: "",
    userOwner: userID,
  });

  const navigate = useNavigate();

  

  const handleImageUpload = (event) => {
    setBook({...book, imageUrl: event.target.files[0].filename});
    console.log(book.imageUrl);
  };

  const handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("imageUrl", selectedImage);
  
     {/* const uploadResponse = await axios.post("http://localhost:2001/book/upload", formData);
      const imageurl = uploadResponse.data.imageUrl;
    console.log("here", uploadResponse.data.imageUrl) */}
  
      await axios.post(
        "http://localhost:2001/book",
        { ...book, imageUrl: formData},
        {
          headers: { authorization: cookies.access_token },
        }
      );
      console.log(book.imageUrl)
  
      alert("Book Added");
      navigate("/");
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  };

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    const { name, value } = event.target;
    setBook({ ...book, [name]: value });

  }
  return <div>
    <h2>Add A New Book</h2>
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit} encType="multipart/form-data">
    <label htmlFor="title">Title: </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="title"
          name="title"
          value={book.title}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
    <label htmlFor="author">Author: </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="author"
          name="author"
          value={book.author}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
    <label htmlFor="pageCount">Page Count: </label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="pageCount"
          name="pageCount"
          value={book.pageCount}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
    <label htmlFor="genra">Genra: </label>
        <input
          type="text"
          id="genra"
          name="genra"
          value={book.genra}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
    <label htmlFor="datePublished">Date Published: </label>
        <input
          type="date"
          id="datePublished"
          name="datePublished"
          value={book.datePublished}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
    <label htmlFor="format">Format: </label> {/*change to check box*/}
        <input
          type="text"
          id="format"
          name="format"
          value={book.format}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
    <label htmlFor="startDate">Start Date: </label>
        <input
          type="date"
          id="startDate"
          name="startDate"
          value={book.startDate}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
    <label htmlFor="endDate">End Date: </label>
        <input
          type="date"
          id="endDate"
          name="endDate"
          value={book.endDate}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
    <label htmlFor="stars">Stars: </label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="stars"
          name="stars"
          value={book.stars}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
    <label htmlFor="bookFeel">How Did I Feel About This Book: </label>
        <input
          type="number"
          id="bookFeel"
          name="bookFeel"
          value={book.bookFeel}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
    <label htmlFor="summary">summary: </label>
        <textarea
          id="summary"
          name="summary"
          value={book.summary}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />

    <label htmlFor="review">review: </label>
        <textarea
          id="review"
          name="review"
          value={book.review}
          onChange={handleChange}
        />
    <input
          type="file"
          accept=".png, .jpg, .jpeg"
          id="imageUrl"
          name="imageUrl"
          onChange={handleImageUpload}
        />

    
    
    <button type="submit">Create Book</button>
    </form>
  </div>;
};
```

Comment: What does "it's not working" mean? Please be as specific as possible about what you expect to happen, what's not happening, and what you've tried / how you've debugged it.

Comment: @AndyRay i am getting this error "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
    at handleImageUpload (http://localhost:2000/static/js/bundle.js:810:35)

Comment: Please edit your question to include the error. Also, please read the error, don't ignore it. Reading the error will show you what's going on. Your issue is your upload button calls `handleImageUpload` on click, which doesn't make sense. Remove that button entirely.